# can Oauth2 server developed in python be accessed from php Oauth client

Tags: php, python, django, oauth-2.0

i have a python django Oauth server and website configured and i need to login via this website from another php website.I cannot find anything regarding this subject anywhere python/php combination oauth login.

Php Client Code:

```
$clientConfig = new ClientConfig(
array(
"authorize_endpoint" => "http://localhost/oauth/php-
oauth/authorize.php",
"client_id" => "foo", 
"client_secret" => "foobar",
"token_endpoint" => "http://localhost/oauth/php-oauth/token.php",
)
);
```

Comment: Connecting to an OAuth2 serveris the same whether it's in PHP, HHVM, or Python. Look up how to connect to Twitter, Facebook, or Google API's, they all use OAuth2.

Comment: @delboy1978uk here the endpoint files are .php file in the client code  while mine are made in python and are being created by django framework.